# How to import this file in my xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to iOS development and XCode. I am trying here to use a library for my project but I can't manage to include it into my main controller. I am using XCode 10.

As I see in the reference project I am using, I should't even have to import it, but yet, it can't seem to recognize when i use the Delegate
Any idea how to process this ? Thanks

I have tried quite a large number of solutions : typo, moving the file, settings,adding it into my libraries ...

```
import "../DTDevices.h"
#import "../DTDevices.h"
import DTDevices.h
....
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are importing the class into a swift file, you do not need to reference the path for your file (Xcode treats all files as a flat surface). You can import just DTDevices.

```
import DTDevices
```

If DTDevices is an objc file, you need to import this file in a bridger file..

https://www.ios-blog.com/tutorials/objective-c/how-to-use-objective-c-classes-in-swift/

Comment: Thank you ! I made a mistake during the bridge part : 
Go to your project settings -> Build Settings and filter by Swift Compiler. Expand “Objective-C Bridging Header” and add (there is an add button right on its side) inside of Debug and Release an “Any Architecture | Any SDK” line and type this value inside of both: “DTDevices.h” (without quotes)